# Why is Javascript disabled in an SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, gecko

Why is having Javascript enabled in an SVG considered insecure? I.e. why was Javascript [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image#Restrictions) in SVG (in Gecko)? What are the security implications if it were not disabled?

Comment: It is disabled only *when it is being used as an image*. Don't you think an image `<img>` tag that can download resources and execute scripts is a little bit dangerous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are often loaded from third-party sites, with the expectation that they will display on a page but cannot alter the page. If SVG images were allowed to run JS, then a web page that merely tried to display an external image would be susceptible to session theft and user impersonation.